# Desktop flash log viewer for windows?

Tags: windows, flash, logging

I was wondering if anyone knew of an application that would show the flash log live as it updates, I made a simple app in VB that is a web browser control that is mapped to the location of my flashlog.txt but I always have to hit F5 and for some reason recently it has stopped working... so, anyone know of one for windows that works well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the free [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) application to monitor log files.  You could point it at flashlog.txt and watch it go.

Be sure to check out the "highlight" feature - it automatically highlights lines that match customizable patterns, which makes it quite easy to locate those lines of interest in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check that you have the [debug version of the player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and that you export the swf in debug mode.

This may be out of context as you may have a specific reason to track the flashlog.txt.
But if you want to simply monitor your SWFs activity there's quite a lot of possibilities out there, here's a few of them:

**Firebug** - In FireFox

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843

Example : `ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "Hello");`

**ThunderBolt** - External Air App

http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/

Example : `Logger.error("Hello");`

**FDB (shipped with FLEX SDK)** - Terminal

[Tutorial](http://installingcats.com/2007/12/07/how-to-use-command-line-debugger-fdb-to-debug-flex-flash-on-mac-os-x/)

Example : `trace("Hello");`